# Importing Data from Website onto Google Sheets without tables/lists

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I'm really new to coding and I'm trying to import data from https://www.bitcointradevolume.com/ onto Google Sheets.

`ImportHTML` and ImportXML doesn't work cos there is no table. Based on what I understand, I would probably need JSON or something like that, but I'm not too sure.

No code to show... You can view the source of the website!

I'm expecting to see the list of prices onto my spreadsheet that is supposed to update whenever the website updates.

Comment: The 24 hour volume prices?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find another website because this one is not possible to be scraped due to JavaScript:

> [image: 0]

More at: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126329/186471**